# Differences between cmdproxy.exe and cmd.exe

Tags: process, shell-command, call-process

What is the difference between:

```
(call-process "cmdproxy"  nil "foo" nil "/c"  "dir")
(call-process "cmd"  nil "foo" nil "/c"  "dir")
```

?

I seem to get exactly the same results in Emacs 25.1 on Windows 10, except  `cmdproxy`  works with the `-c` switch too.

### Update

Probably not everyone knows that Microsoft (Windows) has nothing to do with `cmdproxy.exe`. It is a binary part of Emacs distribution (i.e. made by Emacs developers) in order to call Windows subprocesses. As noted above, I don't see  any sensible benefit over `cmd.exe`.
Hence this question belongs here,  not Windows forums.

Comment: You should ask about the difference between `cmdproxy` and `cmd` in a Windows forum.

Comment: @Nick: please, see the update

Answer (score 4):

I just found [this](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/973d10a34b23f2ce5acc00a90ec9767e6237fefa/nt/cmdproxy.c):

> Proxy shell designed for use with Emacs on Windows 95 and NT. [...]
>   The main function is simply to process the "-c string" option in the way /bin/sh does, since the standard Windows command shells use the convention that everything after "/c" (the Windows equivalent of "-c") is the input string.

Personally, I don't see cases where you are obliged to pass the shell command "-c string". You can always write

```
(format "%sc string" 
    (if (eq system-type 'windows-nt) "/" "-"))
```